# Trouble converting sql statement to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've read through the 101 linq samples and they seem to have pieces of what I'm trying to do but having trouble putting it together. I have a query like so which joins my 'Customers' to some 'Orders' values (e.g. The total of all orders and the number of orders).

```
SELECT * 
FROM cm_Customers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
 SELECT UserID, SUM(Total) as Total, COUNT(OrderID) as Orders 
 FROM cm_orders 
 GROUP BY UserID
) TOTALS ON cm_Customers.UserID = TOTALS.UserID 
ORDER BY TOTALS.Total DESC
```

I figured out how to do a left outer join but I do see any way to get the sums without grouping perhaps? I don't see any examples of grouping for sums then left joining this result back to another select.

```
var x = 
    from c in db.Customers
    join o in db.Orders on c.UserID equals o.UserID into oo
    from o in oo.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { FirstName = c.FirstName, SUM??(o.Total),  };
```

I seem to just be spinning my wheels at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the `group by` after join. The results should be exactly the same:

```
var x = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.UserID equals o.UserID into oo
            from o in oo.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { c, o } by c.UserID into g
            select new {
                Customer = g.FirstOrDefault().c,
                Total = g.Sum(x => x.o.Total)
                Count = g.Select(x => x.o.OrderId).Distinct().Count()
            };
```

Comment: g.Count(x => x.o.OrderID   ... this wants a boolean... i'm not sure what the test condition would be since i just want a count of the rows

Comment: I've updated the answer, but I'm not sure if it's gonna translate into SQL properly.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I had to make one change to filter out nulls as I was always getting at least 1 order back. not sure if this the fastest way:                                                     OrdersCount = g.Where(p => p.o.OrderID != null).Select(x => x.o.OrderID).Distinct().Count()

Comment: You can try moving the predicate into `Count`: `OrdersCount = g.Select(x => x.o.OrderID).Distinct().Count(p => p.o.OrderID != null)`

Comment: You are the linq master. one small correction to your last edit.. since it has only the value at this point, I changed to:                                                                             OrdersCount = g.Select(x => x.o.OrderID).Distinct().Count(x => x != null)

Comment: Sure. I missed the `Select` call before.